# CMake generator expression dependent on source property

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to add a compiler flag to all source files that don't have a specific property set.

The first use case is adding `-Wshadow -Wuseless-cast` to the command line for all non-`GENERATED` files, later on I'd like to add custom properties for other compiler flags.

I'd like to avoid the "trick" of countermanding default compile flags with per-source flags, because that requires subdirectory CMakeLists.txt to be aware of different options, the need to override them and the proper way to extend a list of flags with

```
set_property(
    SOURCE ...
    APPEND_STRING
    PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS "-Wno-shadow ")
```

which IMO is a lot of boilerplate that needs to be duplicated often.

The documentation for generator expressions is awfully silent on checking source properties. Can this be done at all?

Comment: Generator expressions are **not a replacement** for other commands, like `if` or "collect me those targets" things. Generator expressions are mainly for things, which **cannot be expressed by other means**: switch on a conditions, which are not known at configuration stage in multi-configuration build systems. For other cases "boilerplate" is a true way. If you want, you may wrap that code with a macro/function.